# Decryptbypassphrase equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I've recently migrated a huge MSSQL database to MySQL using MySQL Workbench. It worked nearly perfectly, an we're now attempting to rewrite all the stored procedures.
For login, all the password were encrypted using Mssqls method "encryptbypassphrase".

I don't want to demand that all the users change their passwords- is there some equivalent to decryptbypassphrase that will work for MySQL? So that I can keep all the passwords, and the same encryption methods?

Thank you!